# Cannot connect to GPT4 API?

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api, gpt-4

I cannot connect to GPT4's API! In my command prompt I even installed openai and the newest version of python. I am trying to run this in Google Colab, any thoughts?

```
# Install the OpenAI library
!pip install openai

import openai

 # Set your API key here
 openai.api_key = 'YOUR_API_KEY'

 def query_gpt4(prompt):
    response = openai.Completion.create(
        model="gpt-4", 
        prompt=prompt, 
         max_tokens=100
     )
     return response.choices[0].text.strip()

 # Example usage
 prompt = "Translate the following English text to French: 'Hello, how are you?'"
 response = query_gpt4(prompt)
 print(response)
```

I get this error:
APIRemovedInV1                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 19>()
17 # Example usage
18 prompt = "Translate the following English text to French: 'Hello, how are you?'"
---> 19 response = query_gpt4(prompt)
20 print(response)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/openai/lib/_old_api.py in **load**(self)
31     @override
32     def **load**(self) -> None:
---> 33         raise APIRemovedInV1(symbol=self._symbol)
34
35

APIRemovedInV1:

You tried to access openai.Completion, but this is no longer supported in openai>=1.0.0 - see the README at https://github.com/openai/openai-python for the API.

You can run `openai migrate` to automatically upgrade your codebase to use the 1.0.0 interface.

Alternatively, you can pin your installation to the old version, e.g. `pip install openai==0.28`

A detailed migration guide is available here: https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742

Comment: Did you do what the error suggested?

Answer (score 2):

You have to migrate openAI to the new version. That was a major update of the SDK so it gives the error as you see if you have not migrated.

Follow the guide: https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742

If you complete the migration your app should work correctly.